# RTMP broadcast (Youtube API) for live streaming on youtube showing blank screen

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, tokbox

I am using tokboxjs for stream sharing and also using youtube API for RTMP broadcast. After successful broadcast and Bind it will always display a blank screen on youtube.

No error in console
stream rate is healthy

```
var streamResource ={ "snippet": { "title": ajaxLoginInstance.meetingSubject, "isDefaultStream":false }, "cdn":{ //"format":'1080p', "frameRate":'30fps', "resolution":'480p', "ingestionType":'rtmp' } };
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you have a code sample? It is pretty hard to find out whats going wrong with just a short description

Comment: Yes but it is too long to add in comment. how can i debug this issue?

Comment: Then only add the "important" part of it. How do you think, someone could answer your question with no example of what you are doing? :D

Comment: var streamResource ={
    
    "snippet": {
    "title": meetingSubject,
    "isDefaultStream":false
    },
    "cdn":{
    //"format":'1080p',
      "frameRate":'30fps',
      "resolution":'480p',
    "ingestionType":'rtmp'
    }
  };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using tokbox custom-layout with no stylesheet added to it so video streams were not displaying in viewport but streams were always there now i changed layout to horizontalPresentation and now video streams are appearing on viewport.

Comment: I was getting same issue on youtube and it has a problem in custom stylesheet. Thanks